# R Programming - Looking for Average marks obtained by each student in Semester IV

Tags: r

Please help me rectify the following line of code:

```
aggregate(df$marks[which(df$semester="IV")]~df$StudentName,Fun="mean")
```

Thank you,
Kalo

Comment: Hard to help without an explanation and example data.

Comment: Study the documentation. `aggregate`'s formula method has a `data` parameter, which you must use.

Comment: If you want to do it in `data.table`:

    `library(data.table)
    dt <- as.data.table(df)
    dt[semester=="IV", mean(marks), by=c("StudentName")]
    dt[, mean(marks), by=c("StudentName","semester")]`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your data frame correctly, you can do this using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% filter(semester=="IV") %>% group_by(StudentName) %>% summarise(averages=mean(marks))
```